# Self-hosted SMTP server in parallel to Google Apps

Tags: email, g-suite, smtp

I am currently using free version of Google Apps for hosting my email. It works great for my official mails but except for sending out high volume mails (registrations, forgotten passwords, newsletters etc) as there is a limit to how much traffic a particular account may generate (about ~500 emails a day / account ).

I am thinking about setting up my an SMTP server myself. I was wondering if it'll be possible to do that while Google App Mail still works in parallel? How about I setup on a separate subdomain (mail.example.com)?

PS: Paid version of Google Apps is also an option but under my circumstances it is not viable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup your own SMTP server to send email messages from, while using Google Apps in parallel. However, these messages will not be in your "Sent Mail" mail unless you moved using IMAP and replies to these messages will go to the mail servers in your MX records (Google by default).

You can set it up to send using a different sub domain, but that is not a requirement. You can use the same domain. Just call the self hosted SMTP server something different like smtp2.yourdomain.com.

If you are using SPF records [1] for your domain, then make sure to add the SMTP server IP to the list of allowed IP addresses.

[1] http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't setup a SMTP server to send your own mail as well as using google apps. If you want to receive replies etc. back to the same server then you need a seperate subdomain, otherwise you can use the same domain.

Comment: Great. Any pointers on how do I do that? What MX entries and other settings would I need to change?

Also, would it increase the probability of mails ending up in spam folder as the originator IP would be different?

Comment: The MX records control where mail is sent to, there's no need to change them to send from a different location.

Comment: Wouldn't that be considered as "spoofed mail" by other recipient servers if there are no entries to match to?

Comment: No. It's perfectly normal for mail to originate at an SMTP server which is not an MX for the domain.